# How do I add a xsi namespace prefix to an xml using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I try to create following XML using groovy(SoapUI).

Expected XML

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:save xmlns:ns2="http://service.generic.abc.it">
         <arg1 xsi:type="ns4:ContractGroup" xmlns:ns4="http://generic.abc.it" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <discounts xsi:type="ns4:DiscountPrice"></discounts>
         </arg1>
      </ns2:save>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

used code: (not worked)

```
def grUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

// create XmlHolder for request
def requestHolder = grUtils.getXmlHolder("Contract_save#Request")

// find the Node that I am interested in
def requestNodeMain = requestHolder.getDomNode("//*:Body/*:save/*:arg1[1]")

// the Document object is used to create new nodes
def requestDocMain = requestNodeMain.getOwnerDocument()

def WideSearchRQElement = requestDocMain.createElementNS("ns4:DiscountPrice","type:discounts")
requestNodeMain.appendChild(WideSearchRQElement)

requestHolder.updateProperty(true)
```

Comment: Have you tried the given solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, comments inline.

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def xml = builder.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
//Declare the namespaces
    namespaces << [ S:'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 
    xsi: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 
    ns2: 'http://service.generic.abc.it',
    ns4: 'http://generic.abc.it']
//You can see building the xml as you wanted it
    S.Envelope {
        S.Body {
            ns2.save {
                arg1('xsi.type': 'ns4:ContractGroup' ){
                  discounts('xsi.type': 'ns4:DiscountPrice')
                }
            }            
        }        
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

You can try it quickly online <kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/EUDXFa)</kbd>